# htaccess rewrite with variable

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url-rewriting, rule

I'm using joomla I'm trying to pass a variable in htaccess, ec I have to rewrite this address:

```
http:// site.com/en/one/userprofile/avatar3
```

to avatar3 can be every username

```
http:// site.com/en/two/userprofile/avatar3
```

I've tried doing like these but don't work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/en/one/userprofile/(.*)$ http:// site.com/en/two/userprofile/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/one/userprofile/(.*)$ /en/two/userprofile/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.